# how to get file name with multipart from remote url

Tags: php

i have some files with this format on my remote machine like this:

```
123-0.jpeg,123-1.jpeg,123-2.jpeg,123-3.jpeg, ...
544-0.jpeg,544-1.jpeg,544-2.jpeg,544-3.jpeg, ...
```

Now i just want to get all files name that started with 123 from url ( this format 123- * .jpeg ) but i don't know how i can red this names with such format :  123-*.jpeg maybe do some `array` or you know , can someone tell me thank you?!
or if possible just get the name of lasted one in my case its 123-3.jpeg.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking for the glob function?

http://php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php

```
foreach (glob("123-*.jpeg") as $filename) {
  echo "$filename size " . filesize($filename) . "\n";
}
```

**Edit:** Based on your comments, this will probably do what you are looking for: it has some flaws (ex.: remote server changes output), but it should be enough to get you in the right direction.

```
$html = file_get_contents("http://plusmaster.info/screenshots/");

// Note that this pattern returns nothing at the present.
$pattern = '/data-name="(123-[0-9]*\.jpeg)" /';

// If you want to get *-123.jpeg instead, use this:
// $pattern = '/data-name="([0-9]*-123\.jpeg)" /';

preg_match_all($pattern, substr($html,3), $matches, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);

// To dump the whole array of matches:
var_dump($matches[1]);

// To echo the last item in the array
echo end($matches[1]);
```

A couple useful tools for working with Regex in PHP:

1) Rubular is generally great for testing PHP regexes too, even though it was made for Ruby: http://rubular.com/

2) The PHP manual explains preg_match_all more in depth: http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php

Let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: Yep, this is the right answer, if OP has files stored in the same directory.

Comment: thanks but i need to get file names from remote server not same directory

Comment: What kind of access do you have to the remote machine (ssh, ftp, etc.)?  Can you run a script on the remote machine?

Comment: i have windows server 2008 with IIS this is my website:  `plusmaster.info/screenshots/`

Comment: I updated my answer.  It may not be the best solution, but with the limited information that I have, it's the only one that I can be sure will work.  Let me know if you have any questions about it.